# Using Card-io library asks for card details instead of calling up the camera for scanning

Tags: android, cardio

I am new to the `Card-io` library. I have downloaded the library from here [here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK). I have converted the  `.aar`   to  `.jar` file and added to my project, in the `libs` folder. I followed the tutorial which is provided in the above link. I encounter the following problems:

1. I get the following error on the `LogCat` :

   ```
   Failed to load native library: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.creditcardscanner-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libcardioDecider.so
   ```
2. When the button click is fired, I get a page that asks for the `Card` details like the cardnumber and expiry date.

Can anyone please guide me, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not added the `libcardioDecider.so` files. Copy the `aremaabi` folders that are present in the `jni` folders into your `libs` folder. It should work.